# Complex nonlinear system of four variables

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I am stuck on the following problem.
Given the system:
$$\displaystyle S_1=w_1e^{i(\alpha\omega_x+\beta\omega_y)}+w_2e^{i(\gamma\omega_x+\delta\omega_y)}$$
$$\displaystyle S_2=w_3e^{i(\eta\omega_x+\mu\omega_y)}+w_4e^{i(\psi\omega_x+\zeta\omega_y)}$$
I would like to solve it for the two variables:
$\omega_x,\omega_y$
assuming:
$\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\eta,\zeta$ real and $S_1,S_2,w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ complex.
Is there some method to solve it analytically? If not, what is the best method to solve it numerically?

Comment: This amounts to a system of four equations in two unknowns, hence overdetermined (unless the $\omega$ are complex ?!).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: yes the system is overdetermined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\alpha\omega_x+\beta\omega_y+\angle w_1-\angle S_1,v=\gamma\omega_x+\delta\omega_y+\angle w_2-\angle S_1$.

Then the first equation expresses

$$|w_1|\cos u+|w_2|\cos v=|S_1|,\\|w_1|\sin u+|w_2|\sin v=|S_1|.$$

We eliminate $v$ by

$$(|S_1|-|w_1|\cos u)^2+(|S_1|-|w_1|\sin u)^2=|w_2|^2.$$

After transformation, this is a classical

$$2|w_1|(\cos u+\sin u)=2|S_1|^2+|w_1|^2-|w_2|^2,$$
which you can solve for $u$, and then

$$\tan v=\frac{|S_1|-|w_1|\sin u}{|S_1|-|w_1|\cos u}.$$

From $u$ a,d $v$ you deduce the $\omega$'s by solving a linear system. Plugging in the second equation will tell you about the compatibility.

---

Geometrically, you are asking how to rotate two vectors in such a way that they sum to a third one. This is equivalent to the resolution of a triangle of three known sides.

Comment: You have to solve the folowing equation: $\sin(u)+\cos(u)=a$, but if a is a large number how can tuou solve the previous equation?

Comment: @riccardo: the same way that you solve a triangle with sides $1,2,5$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think it should be $|w_1|\sin u+|w_2|\sin v=0$. No imaginary part left on the lhs.